# I am trying to import from selenium and selenium.webdriver.support.ui I have tried many ways to get geckodriver into my usr/bin/ but it is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I am using python 2.7 on a mac and writing in the Terminal. I have made sure that my geckodriver is readable, writable and executable:

```
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 Esi  staff  3600548 31 Oct 19:55 geckodriver
```

The gecko driver is currently residing in my Dropbox folder. I have used:

```
cd Dropbox
sudo cp geckodriver /usr/bin/
```

I have then entered my password and received:

```
cp: /usr/bin/geckodriver: Operation not permitted
```

I have also tried

```
export PATH=$PATH:Dropbox/geckodriver
```

Comment: When you say it isn't working, do you get some error or does it do nothing?

Comment: This sounds like it has nothing to do with Selenium or Python? You are just having problem copying a file with elevated privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your geckodriver is readable, writable and executable in the Dropbox folder. Your problem is about the [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection).

Your user is not able to write in `/usr/bin`.

You could disable the SIP or set in the code the path to the geckodriver:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox( executable_path=r'/whateverPathTo/geckodriver')
```

Or you should set, in the $PATH environment variable, the **absolute path** to the geckodriver.

Comment: I tried the second two methods but both did not work - I have switched to using chrome and chromedriver which worked instantly.

Comment: @ElizabethStudent What are your versions of Selenium, Firefox Browser and geckodriver? Could be that something isn't compatible.

Comment: I think that may be likely as my Firefox is old. Thank you!

Comment: @ElizabethStudent Happy to help. If this answer helped to solved your issue, please mark it as accepted: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers